# "Key not valid for use in specified state" (DPAPI) error when access from different machine

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, dpapi

We use Cryptography.ProtectedData.protect and Cryptography.ProtectedData.Unprotect
for Encryption. The scope is DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine.

The application is hosted on a shared drive. When a user access the application from their own computer it will encrypt a config file which works for this user from this point. However thereafter  if any other user access the application from their own computer on this shared drive the receive the error:
**Key not valid for use in specified state**

It seems that when you access the application remotely from A computer it acts that local machine is A computer not the machine where the application is hosted.

Thanks for any info

Comment: That's the way DPAPI works, you either choose by Machine or by User - are these two users using the same machine?

Comment: Thanks no they access the application from different machines via accessing a shared folder